# Undefined control sequence error message for binary math symbol \medbackslash

Tags: math-mode, undefined

I'm getting the following error message. Any ideas?
[image: Error Screenshot]

Comment: Try with the package **MnSymbol**

Comment: The `\medbackslash` command is defined either by `MnSymbol` or `fdsymbol`. Note that *both* packages change *all* math symbols.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you pleas try with

> \usepackage{MnSymbol}

[image]